# MOSS 2007 - Getting Error When Trying to Add Colleague to My Site - "User Cannot Be Found in the User Profile Store"

Tags: sharepoint

An end user is trying to add some colleagues to his "My Site" within SharePoint. Many of the users he is able to add without an issue. However, some others he gets the error "Firstname Surname cannot be found in the User Profile Store."

I've found others with the same issue elsewhere via Google but haven't found any solutions. Does anybody have any idea what needs to be done to resolve this problem?

Edit: I've attempted to add the same colleague to my site and received the same error so it appears to be a problem with that user who is trying to be added rather than the user who is setting up their site. Not sure how much this helps but it at least rules out one possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to recall that Sharepoint synncs user information in from Active Directory.  The error would indicate Sharepoint doesn't yet know about the user.  Have you treid adding them by email address?

\\Greg

Comment: I just tried that but got the same error. When adding the user it is added from the address book and those users have done things with SharePoint elsewhere on the site, just doesn't seem to work with this for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by doing a full profile import at:

Shared Services Administration: SharedServices1 > User Profile and
Properties > Start full profile import.

Comment: If that fixed the problem, ensure that you have profile imports scheduled at some interval.